# Why does link-time optimization cause a segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, mingw-w64, boost-iostreams, link-time-optimization

I am using **Mingw-w64** v7 and **g++** 10.2 on **Windows** built with the arguments `--mode=gcc-10.2.0 --arch=x86_64 --buildroot=/c/mingw-builds/BuildRoot --update-sources --exceptions=seh --threads=posix --enable-languages=c++ --jobs=48 --rt-version=v7`. I have downloaded and unpacked **bzip2** 1.0.6 from here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/bzip2/. Now I build **boost** 1.76.0 like this in a **MSys2** console:

```
./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=iostreams --prefix=c:/Libraries/boost_1_76_0/InstallRelease
./b2 --layout=system variant=release link=shared address-model=64 threading=multi optimization=speed runtime-link=shared -s BZIP2_SOURCE=C:/Libraries/bzip2-1.0.6 install
```

I would like use **Boost.Iostreams** to compress some streams with **bzip2**. Therefore I create a test file main.cpp with this content:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/bzip2.hpp>

int main() 
{
    {
        std::ofstream file("hello.z", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary);
        boost::iostreams::filtering_ostream out;
        out.push(boost::iostreams::bzip2_compressor());
        out.push(file);
        
        out << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    }

    {
        std::ifstream file_in("hello.z", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
        boost::iostreams::filtering_istream in;
        in.push(boost::iostreams::bzip2_decompressor());
        in.push(file_in);
        
        std::string content(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(in), {});
        std::cout << content << std::endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

If I compile it with

```
 g++ main.cpp -o main.exe --std=c++11  -lboost_iostreams -I/c/libraries/boost_1_76_0/InstallRelease/include -L/c/libraries/boost_1_76_0/InstallRelease/lib
```

set the path on an **Msys2** console with

```
export PATH=/c/Libraries/boost_1_76_0/InstallRelease/lib:/c/mingw-w64-10.2/mingw64/bin
```

and run it, I get

```
$ ./main.exe
Hello World!
```

Now if I delete the directories `bin.v2` and `InstallRelease` from the `boost_1_76_0` directory and build **boost** again, but this time with `cflags=-flto` like this:

```
./b2 --layout=system variant=release link=shared address-model=64 threading=multi optimization=speed runtime-link=shared cflags="-flto" -s BZIP2_SOURCE=C:/Libraries/bzip2-1.0.6 install
```

and run `main.exe` again, I get:

```
$ ./main.exe
Segmentation fault
```

This is not the case, if I use `boost::iostreams::zlib_(de)compressor` instead. If I build **boost** with debug information like this:

```
./b2 --layout=system variant=debug link=shared address-model=64 runtime-link=shared cflags="-flto" -s BZIP2_SOURCE=C:/Libraries/bzip2-1.0.6 install
```

and run `main.exe` within **gdb**, the output is like this:

```
Starting program: C:\...\main.exe #
[New Thread 7460.0x1dec]
[New Thread 7460.0x2508]
[New Thread 7460.0x2cb4]

Thread 1 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

Trying to print a backtrace is not successful, even if `main.exe` has been compiled with the arguments `-O0 -g`:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

What does that mean? Is link-time optimization not as harmful as I had thought? Where is the bug? In the compiler? In **Boost.Iostreams**? Have I made an error? Which one? Or how can I figure out what actually has caused the segmentation fault?

Comment: I faced with the similar thing, but in another context. What I found in my case is [HeapAlloc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/heapapi/nf-heapapi-heapalloc) from msvcrt.dll was a root cause of the issue. Then I've changed memory allocator from default to jemalloc - and error gone. Interesting thing, beside lto same effect can be replicated with havy multi-threading calls (i.e. up 16 threads) to HeapAlloc. Default malloc and free on MinGW uses msvcrt heap allocation. 2. Also you can try to switch distribution of MinGW, for example MSYS2 it links to universal crt.

Comment: You can try to add `-g` flag to main.exe build command line (to add debug info) and invoke `bt` command in gdb when segfault happens to see the call stack. Maybe it will show some something useful.

Comment: @dewaffled I have tried that and added the output to the question. The output is: `Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)`.

Comment: @VictorGubin The debugger output seems to show that the segmentation fault occurs at application startup, doesn't it? In this case no heap allocation has taken place. Do you still think that the MS VC++ runtime may be the culprit?

Comment: By process of elimination you have pretty much narrowed down the issue to one of boost's classes. That's pretty much as far as it can go, without diving into Boost's source. Given that the segfault occurs at startup, my bet would be on static initialization order fiasco being the problem.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik What should I do? Create a boost issue report?

Comment: You could do that, you have a short enough program, a reproducer, that you can attach to the bug report. If the crash requires a particular input file, that can be attached as well. You can also try building the code on Linux and see if it also crashes. Linux will have better runtime debugging information available.

Comment: @VictorGubin I highly doubt that `HeapAlloc` in multi-threaded applications fails, rather it was more likely a bug on your side.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik On my Linux here (g++ 8.3.0) I am not able to reproduce the error. I have reported an issue: https://github.com/boostorg/iostreams/issues/135

Comment: @Benjamin Bihler  look into CRT code, you'll see CRT actually allocates memory on startup.

Comment: @VictorGubin I have tried to build MinGW-w64 with ucrt to verify that. Unfortunately the build fails, I don't really understand why and I probably will not have the time to continue that. Anyway, what would be the outcome of such an experiment? On Linux the same code doesn't lead to a segmentation fault. But if Sam Varshavchik was right and there was a static initialization order fiasco, then many changes to the application might lead **by chance** to a working application. This does not prove that there has been a bug in the changed setting!